# What is Angular Directive for pop-up menu please?

Tags: angularjs, popupmenu

I have a web application to write and in the majority of cases I have a 1 to 1 relationship between objects of Class A and objects of Class B, so I hop from one to the other.  Sometimes it is 1 to many, in this case I need to display a popup menu and let the user take a selection from the menu and then I will navigate as if it was 1 to 1.

All this is brand new code so no legacy JavaScript/J Query exists.

I seldom write web code but from I have learnt recently Angular appears to be an architectural correct way to do things instead of writing my own JavaScript I want to use the correct Angular method.

But I need a start point.  I was looking for a Angular directive and I can see things like input[email] and input[month] but I cannot see input[dropdown] or input[popup].

Can someone please steer me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dropdowns you want to use [html-select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). To dynamically add values to the dropdown use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) with the html select.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks.  This link looks to confirm https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.

Comment: And for the "popup-ness" I suppose my model can have a Singleton? property and if not a singleton I can use ng-show to make it appear when I have 2 or more?  In other words bind ng-show to negative of my singleton property on the model, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "popup-ness." [Are you thinking of a pop-up style modal window that takes focus?](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) UI-Bootstrap does that and will give you some other useful features and options.

Comment: I mean the pop-up is visible sometimes.  No need to take focus or that trouble.  I think ng-show or ng-hide will do it.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yea, ng-show is for displaying something conditionally.